# How to specify from address in PHP email from a website

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a PHP form.  The form works, and can send emails through it.  It doesn't look like it's sending them from a specific email address to the email address I want the emails to go to (xxx@a.com).

I would like these emails to be sent from `yyy@a.com`, which I have configured below.  Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'Contact'; 
$to = 'me@a.com'; 
$subject = 'Contact';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {              
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Your message has been sent!");
            </script>';
    } else { 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Something went wrong, try again.");
            </script>'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

I have tried changing the $from to yyy@a.com, but that doesn't change the email's from address.  Why isn't the From address getting set?

Answer (score 1):

The fourth parameter isn't `from`, it is `extra headers`. So to include an extra `from` header, do this:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'Contact <yyy@a.com>'; // You can combine name and address
$to = 'xxx@a.com'; 
$subject = 'Contact';


$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

$extraHeaders = 'From:'.$from; // Header field + header field value.

if ($_POST['submit']) {              
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $extraHeaders)) { // Pass the extra headers...
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Your message has been sent!");
            </script>';
    } else { 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Something went wrong, try again.");
            </script>'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no authentication system to send an email from a certain address?

Comment: Usually not, which is why it is so easy to send spam. Some receivers do some automatic checks, though. For instance, after receiving the e-mail they would contact the originating server again to verify if the domain name matches the IP. If the answer isn't satisfactory they discard the e-mail.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks! It kind of sucks that you can't authenticate though!